# setup lpd printer to print to printer and file

Tags: shell-script, lpd

In reference to: [Redirect lpd lp to a file?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/304559/redirect-lpd-lp-to-a-file/311484#311484)

What about the scenario where you want to print and store the output in a file at the same time? I cannot seem to make this functionality work. I can get it to send to the printer, send to a text file, but I cannot get it to do both at the same time for each print job encountered. My simple of: file in `/etc/printcap` is:

```
!/bin/sh

Filter for HP Printing to do 10 pitch printing

echo "\033E\033&l0o\033(8U\033(s0p10h12v0s0b3T\033&k3G\033&s0C\c" 

cat

echo "\033E\c"

cat
```

I simply added to the `cat` command `cat>>/usr/myname/store_the_text.txt`. It will not do both.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I fully understand the situation but here is at script which will store and print any input:

```
#! /bin/bash
tee >( cat > arch.$(date +%s).lpd ) | lp
```

I call it `storeandprint` and tested it with:

```
ls | storeandprint
```

The trick is the process-substitution with `>( ... )`. `tee` will send output to this *>()-file* and to stdout.

Comment: ok, I understand the concept, but am struggling with the syntax.  I cannot use bash - using /bin/sh.  Can you give me the /bin/sh command?